# how to group certain values in flask using jinja2?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have my `index.html` looks like this,

```
<div class="ui small feed">
        {% for article in articles %}
          <h4 class="ui header">{{ article.source }}</h4>
            {% if article.comments %}
              <div class="event">
                <div class="content">
                  <div class="summary">
                    <a href="{{ article.comments }}">
                      {{ article.title }}</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            {% else %}
              <div class="event">
                <div class="content">
                  <div class="summary">
                    <a href="{{ article.link }}">
                      {{ article.title }}</a>
                  </div>
                <div>
              </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

previous code results some thing like this,

```
samename
url
samename
url
samename
url
anothername
url
anothername
url
```

how do I get from that to, following one?

```
samename
  url
  url
  url

anothername
  url
  url
```

I tried couple of ways like declaring flag variable(with boolean value) and it always end up with too much code in the presentation side, and it's a bad thing right? can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Your article list is already ordered by article.source?

Comment: yes data is already sorted. can you help me with this. @rick

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupBy(here the [doc](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#groupby))

```
{% for group in articles|groupby('source') %}
  <h4 class="ui header">{{ group.grouper }}</h4>
  {% for article in group.list %}
    {% if article.comments %}
      <div class="event">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="summary">
            <a href="{{ article.comments }}">
              {{ article.title }}
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% else %}
      <div class="event">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="summary">
            <a href="{{ article.link }}">
              {{ article.title }}
            </a>
          </div>
        <div>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this can help you!